# URL beautification

Tags: php, javascript, html, url

I can't seem to figure out how to add an extra "/" to the end of my website's URL without affecting the URLs that are referenced in the file.

So, I want to change the URL from

```
http://url.com/home
```

to

```
http://url.com/home/
```

without affecting the URLs that are embedded in the files.

Do you have any idea on how to do this?

Thanks,
Rob

Comment: What do you mean "URLs that are embedded in the files"?

Comment: @jraede: Relative URLs, presumably, like `<a href="foo">...</a>`.

Comment: @jraede For example `<script src="jquery.js"></script>`. The server will be trying to find it at `home/jquery.js` so it will all bug out.

Comment: Gotcha. In that case, nice answer.

Comment: @Rob why don't you use absolute URLs? e.g. `<script src="/includes/js/jquery.js"></script>`. That won't change regardless of the URL of the page you're on.

Comment: Then just do `<script src="/jquery.js">` so it reads the file from the root.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com//questions/4017582/add-trailing-slash-to-url

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`<base>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) tag in `<head>` section

```
<head>
    <base href="http://mydomain.com/" /> 
</head>
```

With this all relative links will be prefixed with given `base`.

Comment: +1 I had *completely* forgotten about `base`. Standards reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-base-element

Comment: After I've updated my page to use this it gets stuck on loading. Any ideas? Scratch that, it's not stuck, it just loads slow and then ultimately returns to a page that doesn't have the referenced pages loaded

Comment: @Rob: That suggests that some of the URLs were relying on the previous version of the base.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder How would I go about finding the previous version of `base`?

Comment: @Rob: For `http://url.com/home`, the default base is `http://url.com/`. For `http://url.com/home/`, it's `http://url.com/home/`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I mistyped the URL. Thanks for your help.